# How to preserve formats when generating a CSV file from DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the below code to generate a CSV file from DataGridView and working fine. But it is not preserving the exact formats. For example, I have 125600.00 in one cell and 08 in another cell in the DataGridView. When I opened the CSV file using Excel, it is showing them as 125600 and 8. And when I opened the CSV file using a notepad, it shows them correct 125600.00 and 08. Is there something that I can do to see the same formats in the excel?
Thanks for any suggestions.

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sbMainFile = new StringBuilder();
        int dgcolcount = this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < dgcolcount; i++)
        {
            sbMainFile.Append(this.dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name);
            if (i < dgcolcount - 1)
            {
                sbMainFile.Append(",");
            }
        }
        sbMainFile.Append("\r\n");

        StringBuilder sbRow = null;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            sbRow = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sbRow.Append(row.Cells[i].Value.ToString());
                if (i < dgcolcount - 1)
                {
                    sbRow.Append(",");
                }
            }
            sbMainFile.AppendLine(sbRow.ToString());
        }

        SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();
        savefile.FileName = "default";
        savefile.Filter = "CSV Files | *.csv";
        savefile.DefaultExt = "csv";

        if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(savefile.FileName))
                sw.Write(sbMainFile.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your Notepad test shows that the format is indeed preserved, so you are asking an excel import specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the "column values" as a string; e.g. 08 as ="08"

change

```
sbRow.Append(row.Cells[i].Value.ToString());
```

to

```
sbRow.AppendFormat("=\"{0}\"", row.Cells[i].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I wanted. Do you also know if there is a way to write the column names in bold format. I want them highlighted in the excel when I open it. Is it possible or do I have to do it manually? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Always a pleasure to help out.  Sorry, but its not possible to include formatting info in a CSV.

Comment: The code works fine after I changed it to,       sbRow.AppendFormat("=\"{0}\"", row.Cells[i].Value.ToString());         When I opened the spreadsheet, some cells have a triangle appeared at the top left corner of the cell and some don't. When I highlight the cell with a warning message, it says "The formula in this cell differs from the formulas in this area of the spreadsheet". Any comments are helpful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. That is actually a problem with Excel formatting your data for you. You don't actually lose any data. You simply have to specify the format in Excel. (If you click on one of your cells where the format is mangled you can actually see the "raw" value in the f(x) editor.)